# C++ Inherited Virtual Method Still Uses Base Class Implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a base class called `Packet`:

```
// Header File
class Packet {
public:
    virtual bool isAwesome() const {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and an inherited class called `AwesomePacket`:

```
// Header File
class AwesomePacket : public Packet {
public:
    virtual bool isAwesome() const {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, when I instantiate an `AwesomePacket` and call `isAwesome()`, the method returns `false` instead of `true`. Why is this the case?

Comment: could you include the code where you instantiate it and call the method?

Comment: To be more precise: could you include a real and complete example, one that compiles out of the box. And please tell us which compiler your are using, which compiler options are active etc.

Comment: You don't need to prefix the methods in the descendant (child) class with `virtual`.

Comment: Thomas, you are right, but I find it rather useful to mark methods overwritten in child class with virtual - makes it obvious that this was intentional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By any chance is your code calling isAwesome in the Packet constructor:

```
Packet::Packet()
{
    // this will always call Packet::isAwesome
    if (isAwesome())
    {
    } 
}
```

Even if this Packet constructor is being used to construct the parent object of an AwesomePacket object, this will not call AwesomePacket::isAwesome.  This is because at this point in time the object is not yet an AwesomePacket.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on how you call the method. Consider this:

```
AwesomePacket ap;
bool awesomeness0( ap.isAwesome()); // true, call is direct, not through vtable

AwesomePacket& rap( ap );
bool awesomeness1( rap.isAwesome()); // true, call is direct, not through vtable

Packet p( ap ); // WRONG (but legal): slicing child instance into space of parent
bool awesomeness2( p.isAwesome()); // false, call is direct, not through vtable

const Packet& rp( ap ); // the right way
bool awesomeness3( rp.isAwesome()); // true, call is through vtable

const Packet* pp( &ap ); // also the right way
bool awesomeness4( pp->isAwesome()); // true, call is through vtable
```

This is to say that polymorphism in C++ only works via reference or a pointer to base.

#### Edit:

Don't forget to add a **virtual destructor** in the base class.

#### Edit:

It also depends on *where* you call your virtual method, see the answer by **R Samuel Klatchko**.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your last example should be `pp->isAwesome()`.

Comment: The comment on your second example (for `awesomeness1`) is incorrect. Since `rap` is a reference, the call *is* through the vtable, not direct. It is correct that `true` is returned though.

Comment: A mistake only a Java programmer would make, passing an object by value.

Comment: Jon-Eric, you are right, sort of. The compiler already knows the exact object type, so it *doesn't need* to go through the vtable, and might just generate direct instead of virtual call.